# How to do calculation with inputs generated by foreach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have an `foreach` returning multiple items from mysql db. Each object is in an input field in my html.

I want to calculate 2 input values and display them in a third as a result.

It works when i have only 1 set of inputs (quantity * unit = result), but using foreach will assign each unit and result input the same class, therefore my js doesn't seem to work.

**My target is to have a list of items from mysql generated with foreach and let the user define a quantity value, this would calculate the total.
But at the moment, when i change the qty value, it calculates with all input_price_unit inputs.**

I have 3 inputs:

- 1 with class = `input_itm_qty`
- 1 with class = `input_price_unit`
- 1 with class = `input_price_total`

Below is my function:

```
 $(".price_calc").keyup(function(){
              var val1 = +$(".input_itm_qty").val();
              var val2 = +$(".input_price_unit").val();
              $(".input_price_total").val(val1*val2);
       });
```

Comment: show some HTML please

Comment: Also need a better explanation of expected behavior. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap (group) your elements into some common parents, say for example the class is `.someParentClass` than you could do like:

```js
$(".price_calc").on("input", function(){
    var $parentElement = $(this).closest(".someParentClass");
    var val1 = +$parentElement.find(".input_itm_qty").val();
    var val2 = +$parentElement.find(".input_price_unit").val();
    $parentElement.find(".input_price_total").val(val1*val2);
}).trigger("input");
```

```css
.someParentClass{border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
[type=number]{text-align: right;}
[disabled] {background:0; border:0;}
```

```html
<div class="someParentClass">
  FOOS<br>
  <input class="input_itm_qty price_calc" type=number value=1 min=0> QTY<br>
  <input class=input_price_unit type=number disabled value=20> $<br>
  <input class=input_price_total type=number disabled>  TOTAL
</div>

<div class="someParentClass">
  BARS<br>
  <input class="input_itm_qty price_calc" type=number value=1 min=0> QTY<br>
  <input class=input_price_unit type=number disabled value=35> $<br>
  <input class=input_price_total type=number disabled>  TOTAL
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```